# How to open an url from android webview app in another app

Tags: android, webview

I am making an Android webview app to share some useful urls. And when user clicks on a url, it should be opened in a targeted app like facebook, neither in external browser, nor inside the webview. How could I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add an edit text and load that text

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the help of Intent.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + 
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScriptInterface to pass deepLink from webView to your java/kotlin class and just open that deep link there!

see
[JavaScriptInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357191/how-to-pass-data-from-javascript-to-android-webview-in-this-case)
and
[deepLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057911/how-to-create-deep-link-for-an-android-application/41058139)